# Any online tool or website we can join together to pray rosary real time?

Tags: audio, internet, religion

Is there any online tool or website that permits people to join together in praying the rosary (and /or other prayers like Divine Mercy Prayer, Padre Pio Prayer...)?

People can pray and have a feeling of praying in community?

I think these online places would be better if they meet conditions below:

1. People can listen to the voice of my praying at real time,
   to make sure that I am "praying" at that exact moment.
2. My prayer audio mp3 files can be saved to the cloud if I wish, 
   so that years later I can come back and listen to my own prayers again.
3. If I wish , I can publish my pray recordings to contribute to the public domain, so the newbie prayers can learn from my praying, also people can encourage each other on praying through this way of sharing.

I am just wondering if someone has already build up such kind of tools/websites... If not yet, would some programmers be interested in building one ?

Thank you a lot !

Comment: Use a tool such as Discord. [This Discord channel](https://discord.gg/9TYfGSm) prays the rosary regularly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any software people can join together to pray prayers real time?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/72278/any-software-people-can-join-together-to-pray-prayers-real-time)